# Parameters CrossBand Like XRCrossBandBox

Tags: vb.net, devexpress, xtrareport

I have a parameter Like the pictures Below : 
[image: XRLabel]

How to Pull The XRLabel(Parameters) From GroupHeader1 to GroupFooter1 Like XRCrossbandBox did ?

Answer (score 0):

unfortunately there is no such built in functionality